# Why were these questions migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration

To my surprise, today we had two questions migrated here:

- https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/571/when-did-scientists-first-postulate-that-earths-atmosphere-might-have-an-upper
- https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/567/when-was-it-discovered-that-the-stars-are-not-all-lying-on-the-same-sphere

Regardless of whether or not we *should* have questions from other sites migrated here, I'm wondering why *these* questions were migrated here. I realize that this may have been purely the decision of the history community, but it seems nonsensical to migrate the questions here for a few reasons:

1. They've each garnered a fair amount of attention on History
2. They don't appear to be off-topic on History
3. They already have accepted answers
4. They're exactly 7 days old

Can anyone provide some rationale for migrating these questions here?

In case quid's comment is deleted, I'll add that there is [a meta discussion on History](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2040/lost-rep-because-your-answer-was-migrated-to-history-of-science-and-math) about this.

Comment: Somebody complains about it on their meta (for orthogonal reasons) so we might soon know http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/2040/lost-rep-because-your-answer-was-migrated-to-history-of-science-and-math It was moved by a per-site moderator not SE staff, and [from a remaining comment](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/571/when-did-scientists-first-postulate-that-earths-atmosphere-might-have-an-upper#comment1174_571) it seems somebody proposed but somebody also objected. It is a bit strange but basically only that mod will know the answer.

Comment: One more thing: if we decide we do not want it, we can close it and it is returned to sender. But then we perhaps should not close it just to make a point. [I did not look carefully at the question, I do not know if it is good or not for us.] (It would then also be closed there, at least initially.)

Comment: @quid I decided to go out on a limb and create an account and write up [an answer](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/2040/lost-rep-because-your-answer-was-migrated-to-history-of-science-and-math/2041#2041). What do you think?

Comment: Seems fine. Just, as said, we *can* migrate it back easily if we want. Usual closer here would achieve this.

Comment: @quid Sure, but I'm reluctant to close because, as you said, "we perhaps should not close it just to make a point." I looked at the question earlier and it seems fine.

Comment: I voted to close this now. It seems they kind of want it back on history.SE and this is the way to achieve this.

Comment: @quid I just did the same for both questions.

Comment: It seems to me that these questions were a better fit here in the first place.  If they have answers on History, it *is* odd to migrate them now, but migrating them has this benefit: It signals that HSM is a good place for such questions.  In theory, questions like this one should come here, first, just as TeX.SE questions used to appear on StackOverflow, but now have their own home.  That said, the line between appropriate subjects for HSM and thos appropriate for History will never be clear; that can't be helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer this question as literally asked: well-meaning History SE users who seemed to want to give HSM a boost left several comments and flags on those posts requesting migration, so a History site mod complied. I don't know why those two questions, specifically, were chosen.

I reversed both migrations yesterday because

- we generally don't migrate posts of the type you described
- the community reaction in this meta post and the one on History (which I also [just answered](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2045/2773))
- to avoid setting up a precedent for a "pipeline" that exists "just because it's always been done that way," rather than as the result of a reasoned discussion

As one of the History mods mentioned on the other meta, this site is a "proper subset" of that one, so questions that are on-topic in both places are probably going to appear there a lot, going forward. I encourage you to work with their community to figure out a better plan for handling migrations (and other interactions) in the future. (I'm aware that as I'm writing this, your site doesn't have pro tem mods yet, but that should be resolved in the very near future.)

For some more background, please see our company blog post [*Respect the community – your own, and others’*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/); it's getting on in years, but still quite accurate in describing our philosophy/position.